# send image > but not upload image

Tags: php, facebook, attachment

I am playing with the facebook sdk, and want to allow our users the ability to post an image to their albums, but NOT the ability to upload the image.

Essentially, we have a dynamic page for logged in users that creates dynamic images on the fly.

Checking over the facebook SDK , I can get everything to work fine, if I allow the user to "upload" an image, but I cannot figure out how to attach the image that is already on the webpage ..

eg. lets say image on page is https://stackoverflow.com/images/my_image.jpg

In the facebook SDK: ( snipped code ) - for **uploading** an image

```
if(empty($code)){ 
      $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
       . "client_id=" .  $app_id 
       . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
       .  "&scope=publish_stream";
      echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url 
      . "'</script>");
     }
    else {
      $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id 
       . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
       . "&code=" . $code;
      $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
      $params = null;
      parse_str($response, $params);
      $access_token = $params['access_token'];

     // Show photo upload form to user and post to the Graph URL
     $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?"
     . "access_token=" .$access_token;

     echo '<html><body>';
     echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'
     .$graph_url .' "method="POST">';
     echo 'Please choose a photo: ';
     echo '<input name="source" type="file"><br/><br/>';
     echo 'Say something about this photo: ';
     echo '<input name="message" 
         type="text" value=""><br/><br/>';
     echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload"/><br/>';
     echo '</form>';
     echo '</body></html>';
```

So my question is, is there a way we can send a particular image , rather than upload an image within the above form ?

This could be the most obvious question known to man, I just am going google eyed trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll only be able to post a link to an image in this way. If you want to post the actial image to Facebook, you'll have to download the image to your server first.

Something as simple as `file_get_contents(PATH_TO_IMAGE)` will work just fine. You can always remove the file from your server once it's posted to Facebook.

There are a few methods detailed [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2718610/upload-photo-to-album-with-facebooks-graph-api) on how to upload a photo without the upload form that is given in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, so how would that be represented as a form field ? or is it hidden ?

Comment: @422 - I've added a link to another post on the site that explains a few methods of uploading...

Comment: Strangely enough, I was reading that page before I posted here.

Comment: @422 - As you can see all the methods there actually have the image on the server before posting... If you only have a URL then you'll only be able to post a link to the photo.

Comment: I think because the image is created using gd, and php. We may need to add a download button ( hide the facebook upload form ) and on completion trigger the upload form. Seems to be the best work around hey.